# Applications to validate atomic IO operations on a storage device?

Tags: mysql, validation, io, innodb, atomic

Are there any applications available to validate atomicity of IO operations on a storage device? I'm using an implementation in 'mysql' to send atomic IO requests.

Are there any IO tools such as IOmeter/vdbench/innosim that can perform atomic IO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check FIO - https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/HOWTO

Very powerful tool with large community.

It allows you to build various IO scenarios as for block devices so for file systems.